# Inheritance of Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, inheritance

Let me sketch the situation. I have a bunch of forms with inheritance already implemented.

Example:

```
 Form A       - Form A1 (inheritance)
              - Form A2 (inheritance)
 Form B       - Form B1 (inheritance)
              - Form B2 - FormB21 (inheritance)
                        - FormB22 (inheritance)
              - Form B3 (inheritance)
 Interface 1  - Form 1A (implementation)
              - Form 1B (implementation)
              - Form 1C (implementation)
```

Lets presume that

> the forms A1, A2,B21 & 1A contain a field 'Authors'

and

> forms 1A,1C,B3,A2 contain a field named 'Origin'.

`Authors` is a `TextBox`, `Origin` is a `ComboBox`.

Right now I want to group my `inputcontrole` into a single superclass (where all my forms will inherit from). How would I do this without creating a `Form` where all the forms inherit from?

I've tried to let them inherit from a standard class but I've made an error somewhere I suppose:

```
Public Class superclass
       Inherits Windows.Forms.Form

       Public Sub New()
           Mybase.New()
       End Sub

       Public Overridable  Sub InputcontroleAuthors()
       Public Overridable  Sub InputcontroleOrigin()
End Class
```

*Note:* I wish to avoid the use of `Shared` functions as well.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I updated your question. There was a typo I guess in your code, it had `Inherts` instead of `Inherits`. Can you confirm this in your own code?

Comment: Yea, it was a typo. it was just example code i posted (with almost no reference to my actual code). My real code is a lot more extended and would make the question way too long. I'm in search of a best-practice/design pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an interface which will contain all the controls (`Authors` and `Origin` in this case). Then implement this interface in the desired forms accordingly.

Comment: As the datacheck is the same over all the forms for those specified fields, i would rather opt for inhertance. I would want to avoid redundant code.

Comment: @svranken - Inheritance is often over-used and should not always be favoured. Composition is quite often the better choice. And you see that a lot with Windows Forms. Perhaps you need to write a small component you can re-use on all the forms?

Comment: I would prefer `Composition` over `Inheritance`.

Comment: After some research between when to use `inheritance` and when to use`composition`, i have decided to ditch the idea of inheritance. I had indeed written some small component that is both more performant & readable.

Comment: @svranken great to know that!